WebService how to prevent async calls
We have a situation where a user submits an xml file to a server, the file is then checked for unique references and the new references are stored in a database.  If they submit the same references again an error message is sent back, and the duplicate references are not stored in the database.
This appears to be working well until some hotshot decides to blast the server with lots of Async calls, and this seems to fail because the unique reference checks are simultaneous and slip through the net.
Is there any way to prevent this by stopping async calls to the server?
I've created a dictionary of ip addresses and threadIds and try to prevent 2 calls processing at the same time

"the file is then checked for unique references" -- How? Are you querying the database for a record with the same XML value?

Fundamentally you can't.  Unless the calls are only ever being sent from code you've written in your own client application(s), which appears to not be the case.  Your options are to make your API method handle concurrent calls, or simply document the behavior as being unsupported and let it fail.  The former is what I would expect as a consumer, given your description of this API.

Those aren't lots of async calls, they're normal calls that happen faster than you expected. 2 clients can post the same request at the same time. You can't control how the clients make those calls anyway. This problem is inherent in all multi-user/concurrent systems

There are a lot of ways to handle this. You could queue such requests to eg a BackgroundService that processes them one by one and makes the appropriate checks. You can have per-user/client queues, again processing one item at a time per client. You can use rate limiting or throttling middleware, or you can store some unique document ID in eg a ConcurrentDictionary that's used to only allow one unique document to be processed at a time. For a load balanced farm you could use Redis

The important part is that the "tag" or ID should be generated, checked and stored before you start processing the rest of the document.

Use the database to enforce uniqueness; it's a problem your database vendor has already solved

You can't change the async behavior, but you can implement a singleton class that implements a lock statement (C#) or SyncLock (VB) to ensure that your function processes one request at a time.  You can call the singleton function from your controller.  Each request will inherently wait for previous calls to the function to complete.  In effect, you keep the async functionality of the controller method but process each call to your singleton function serially.
